# Nvida proprietary driver 331.113 vs Xorg Nvidia-346

Tags: xorg

I have a 14.04 Ubuntu and it's working great although there's something bothering me. I am using the Xorg noveau (according to the additional driver window) and installed nvidia prime which uses nvidia-346.

How do I update the proprietary driver to 346 instead of it still showing 331.113 on the additional driver list?

Answer (score 0):

Probably You did it already, but if not, just add ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa to Your repos:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

Regards,
Mario.